# Using Realm with a framework for WatchKit

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Ok - so I'm very new to frameworks and Realm, and I was wondering how exactly I'd use Realm with a custom framework for accessing the data via WatchKit. I know your supposed to change the Realm directory to an App Group but I'm not exactly sure how to tie that in with a framework. Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Storing your data in an app group is completely separate from using frameworks. As for the framework part, you will want to be sure to link `Realm.framework` with both your main application target and your watch extension target.